# Teradataml (Teradata Python) : Does Teradata Python Package provide any sample datasets?

Tags: python, teradata

Does Teradata Python Package provide any sample datasets for the user to try out various analytic functions?

Answer (score 1):

The Teradata Python Package provides various APIs with sample datasets. The sample datasets can be loaded using a helper function called "load_example_data()"

This function accepts 2 arguments:

1. *function_name* - this is a predetermined value. It is a prefix name of the example JSON file to be used to load data. E.g. dataframe_example.json or adaboost_example.json
2. *table_name* - this specifies the name of the table to be created in the database.

E.g.

```
from teradataml.dataframe.dataframe import DataFrame
from teradataml import load_example_data
from teradataml.context.context import *

con = create_context(host="myhost", username="myusername", password="mypassword")
load_example_data("dataframe","sales")
df = DataFrame("sales")
df
              Feb    Jan    Mar    Apr    datetime
accounts                                          
Yellow Inc   90.0    NaN    NaN    NaN  04/01/2017
Alpha Co    210.0  200.0  215.0  250.0  04/01/2017
Jones LLC   200.0  150.0  140.0  180.0  04/01/2017
Orange Inc  210.0    NaN    NaN  250.0  04/01/2017
Blue Inc     90.0   50.0   95.0  101.0  04/01/2017
Red Inc     200.0  150.0  140.0    NaN  04/01/2017


load_example_data('adaboost','housing_train')
df1=DataFrame("housing_train") 
df1
       price  lotsize  bedrooms  bathrms  stories driveway recroom fullbase gashw airco  garagepl prefarea homestyle
sn                                                                                                                  
183  58000.0   4340.0         3        1        1      yes      no       no    no    no         0       no  Eclectic
366  99000.0  13200.0         2        1        1      yes      no      yes   yes    no         1       no  Eclectic
202  53900.0   2520.0         5        2        1       no      no      yes    no   yes         1       no  Eclectic
265  50000.0   3640.0         2        1        1      yes      no       no    no    no         1       no   Classic
305  60000.0   5800.0         3        1        1      yes      no       no   yes    no         2       no  Eclectic
101  57000.0   4500.0         3        2        2       no      no      yes    no   yes         0       no  Eclectic
427  49500.0   5320.0         2        1        1      yes      no       no    no    no         1      yes   Classic
284  45000.0   6750.0         2        1        1      yes      no       no    no    no         0       no   Classic
244  27000.0   3649.0         2        1        1      yes      no       no    no    no         0       no   Classic
509  87000.0   8372.0         3        1        3      yes      no       no    no   yes         2       no  Eclectic
```

Taking it further these datasets can be used for various operations:
Example 1 for dataframe:

Create a dataframe from view

```
get_context().execute("CREATE VIEW mysales AS SELECT * FROM sales")
df2 = DataFrame("mysales", index_label="Jan")
df2
         accounts    Feb    Mar    Apr    datetime
Jan                                               
NaN    Yellow Inc   90.0    NaN    NaN  04/01/2017
200.0    Alpha Co  210.0  215.0  250.0  04/01/2017
150.0   Jones LLC  200.0  140.0  180.0  04/01/2017
NaN    Orange Inc  210.0    NaN  250.0  04/01/2017
50.0     Blue Inc   90.0   95.0  101.0  04/01/2017
150.0     Red Inc  200.0  140.0    NaN  04/01/2017
```

Assign new column expressions in a dataframe.

`assign(self, drop_columns = False, **kwargs)` --- This returns a new dataframe without modifying the existing dataframe.

`drop_columns = False` -- default value, it will retain columns form previous dataframe. If it is 'true' then columns that are not specified in assign are removed from the resulting dataframe. Calculate the sum of Feb and Jan sales

```
a=df.Feb
b=df.Jan
df.select(['Feb','Jan']).assign(sum=a+b)
     Feb    Jan    sum
0   90.0    NaN    NaN
1  210.0  200.0  410.0
2  200.0  150.0  350.0
3  210.0    NaN    NaN
4   90.0   50.0  140.0
5  200.0  150.0  350.0


df.assign(drop_columns = True, sum=a+b)
     sum
0    NaN
1  410.0
2  350.0
3    NaN
4  140.0
5  350.0
```